# Kinematics initial velocity

Tags: physics, kinematics

A  grape is tossed straight up in the air and caught in the mouth. if the mouth is 1 foot higher than the point where the grape is released in the grape enters the mouth at 25 ft./s what was the initial velocity of the tossed grape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$v_f^2=v_o^2+2g\Delta x$

You have your final velocity, $v_f$. You also have a value for $\Delta x$, as you know the grape travels $1$ foot up. Finally, $g=32 ft/s^2$ at the surface of Earth. Can you proceed?

Comment: Yes thank you so much

Comment: No problem. You may want to consider accepting the answer by clicking the check mark.

Comment: I got 26.25ft/s

Comment: How did you arrive at that answer?

Comment: 625=Vo^2+2(-32)(1)

Comment: Do you know why people are -1 my post

Comment: Likely because you did not show any effort in solving the problem. People here are glad to help! All that we ask is that you show some of your efforts in solving the problem. This makes it more likely for you to get quality answers that answer your question at your level of understanding.